# Show Images with Padding In ImageView with both side scroll

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I am facing problem showing dynamic image in view Pager I want show padding between images I want if user is on first image have last image on left side side with padding and same when user on last image have 
first image on right side with both left and right side scroll

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:gravity="center">


                    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/myview_pager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:clipToPadding="false"
                        android:foregroundGravity="center"
                        android:overScrollMode="never" />
                </LinearLayout>
```

View Pager Code show auto image

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (myViewPagerAdapter.getCount() == page) {
                page = 0;
            } else {
                page++;
            }
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(page, true);
            handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
        } catch (Exception ee) {

            Log.e("runable exception  ", "image  " + ee.getMessage().toString());


        }
    }
};
```

Arrays of images

```
     private void imageSliderFliper(String[] addsArray, String[] addsArray_id) {

        myViewPagerAdapter = new SliderPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), addsArray, addsArray_id);
        viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setPadding(80, 0, 80, 0);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);
    }


View Pager Listener

    @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

              page = position;
        }


     @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            if (arg0 == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = viewPager.getAdapter();
                if (pagerAdapter != null) {
                    int itemCount = pagerAdapter.getCount();
                    if (itemCount < 2) {
                        return;
                    }
                    int index = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
                    if (index == 0 ) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(itemCount - 2, false);
                    } else if (index == itemCount - 1) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
                    }
                }



Adapter Class

    public class SliderPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    String[] gallery;
    String[] addsArray_id;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    CustomProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    public ServerUrlClass serverUrlClass = new ServerUrlClass();
    public String TAG = "SliderPagerAdapter";


    public SliderPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] gallery, String[] addsArray_id) {
        this.context = context;
        this.gallery = gallery;
        this.addsArray_id = addsArray_id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        View view = (View) object;
        container.removeView(view);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slider_adapter_layout, container, false);
        ImageView imageView;
        CardView cardView;

        imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.slider_iv);
        cardView = view.findViewById(R.id.card_pager_id);
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(gallery[position])
                .into(imageView);


        Log.e(TAG, "image_position  " + position);
        Log.e(TAG, "image_path  " + gallery[position]);

        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                get_All_Notification(addsArray_id[position]);
            }
        });

        container.addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return gallery == null ? 0 : gallery.length;
    }
```

Comment: please anyone who can help me to solve this problem I am facing